# getting started with davlib.py

Tags: python, webdav

I want to write a script to connect and access a webdav server. I found out that there is a

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/davlib.py
```

But how to use it? There is no tutorial, no documentation and nothing to google. Anybody able to write a small hello world for it?

the test webdav server is on `localhost:80/webdav` and there is a `davtest.txt` file with the word `dav` inside.

```
$ cd <path_to_webdav>
$ ls
davtest.txt
$ cat davtest.txt
dav
```

I can read python, so if I could just connect and read that there is a file called `davtest.txt` or maybe even it's content I think I could get started working with the source. Not knowing how webDAV works and not knowing `davlib.py` both together is quite tough, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [webdav-lib](https://launchpad.net/python-webdav-lib) I could solve that problem:

```
    url = "davs://localhost:80/webdav/davtest.txt"   
    r = ResourceStorer(url)
    result = r.downloadContent().read()
```

Answer (score 0):

To do a simple get request using davlib

```
import davlib
import base64

host = 'myhost'
protocol = 'myprotocol'
username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'

url = '{}://{}/{}'.format(protocol, host, some_file_path)
d = davlib.DAV(protocol=myprotocol, host=myhost)
auth_token = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' %(username, password)).strip()
header = {"Authenication": "Basic %s' %auth_token}

d.get(url,header)
```

Basic authentication is usable only on https. For more (dry) details on webDAV, see the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918).

The most mature webDAV client library I've found is [python-webdav-library](https://launchpad.net/python-webdav-lib)